# SQL Server : statistical functions on stored procedure result?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

### Background

I have a stored procedure which returns a large set of electricity consumption measurement data. Each record consists of date and time of the measurement and four values measured. Rate at which the measurement is performed ranges from seconds to minutes, in my example (as well as in my real data) the interval is 15 minutes, but may be lower.

Because of the way the data are stored (all values measured are compressed and stored in single column in raw format) the stored procedure I'm using is calling an external assembly which processes the data and returns result set.

### Example

```
EXEC dbo.sp_get_energy_consumption @Identify, @StartTime, @EndTime, @Args
```

Now the stored procedure takes some arguments. `@Identify` is `int` and represents identifier of the measurement device. `@Args` is `nvarchar` and indicates which of the four measured values will be included in the result set. Both `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` are pretty straightforward, they are `datetime` and are used to limit the range of the records.

The stored procedure itself is defined as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_energy_consumption
    @identify int,
    @startTime datetime,
    @endTime datetime,
    @args nvarchar(60)
AS
    EXTERNAL NAME Procedury.StoredProcedures.akd_energy_consumption_list
```

When executed, depending on arguments, the result may look like this.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_get_energy_consumption 1, N'2013-01-08 00:00:00', N'2013-01-09 00:00:00', N'i,e'

ID   | Time                | V1     | V2    | V3    | V4    |
1    | 2013-01-08 15:30:00 | 111.42 | 0.24  | NULL  | NULL  |
2    | 2013-01-08 15:45:00 | 111.90 | 0.24  | NULL  | NULL  |
3    | 2013-01-08 16:00:00 | 112.34 | 0.24  | NULL  | NULL  |
4    | 2013-01-08 16:15:00 | 112.96 | 0.24  | NULL  | NULL  |
...
```

### Problem

The web application I'm about to develop should visualize these data in a form of charts representing selected date range. I will also have to group the records by hours, days, weeks or months depending on date range and chart scale, because transferring about 3,000 records to client just to render some small one month chart is a no go. I have to cut the numbers and calculate some minimums, maximums, averages and standard deviation for each day of the month or week, for example.

I'm quite new in SQL Server so I've Googled a little bit and I found a possible way in transforming the stored procedure into table-valued function, so wrote a very simple TVF which would basically just call the stored procedure and return a table I could use to perform another `SELECT`s on, but I failed because SQL Server don't allow me to `INSERT EXEC` into TVF result table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_get_energy_consumption(@Identify int, @StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime, @Args nvarchar(30))
RETURNS @ConsumptionList TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Time DATETIME,
    V1 FLOAT NULL,
    V2 FLOAT NULL,
    V3 FLOAT NULL,
    V4 FLOAT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @ConsumptionList
    EXEC dbo.sp_get_energy_consumption @Identify, @StartTime, @EndTime, @Args

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure fn_get_energy_consumption, Line 16
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.

Another possibility I did not tried yet could be using `OPENROWSET` which is something, I would like to avoid, if possible.

I'm also a little bit concerned about overall performance, because on my 3 years old quad-core workstation it takes about 5 minutes to execute stored procedure call returning about 6,800 records (almost 2.5 months) with all four measured values (it takes half the time with only two selected) and there is nothing I can do about it, if not caching it in some table or something.

But for now I would be quite happy to figure out how to get a table from the stored procedure.

### Update 1

Because of poor performance of the stored procedure I'm thinking of writing periodic task executing long-running CLR stored procedure (`sp_get_energy_consumption`) and saving results into regular table serving as a cache. This way I will achieve what I would get by using table-valued function with much lower execution time for later queries.

As for now, the only disadvantage that comes to my mind is giving up access to real-time data, because there will always be some delay given by interval between periodic task execution.

Comment: Do you have write access to the database?

Comment: As long as I'm in my testing environment I do, there is no real production environment accessible to me yet. I was supplied with real data only, which comes with complete database structure.

Comment: `dbo.sp_get_energy_consumption` is just a name for external CLR stored procedure.

Comment: You shouldn't name your stored procedures `sp_anything` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't have your data or statistical SP, this syntax is slightly off.
While my normal instinct is to use a table variable; apparently those are explicitly not allowed.  Instead I'm using a temp table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STEVETEST] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Identify INT,
@StartTime DATETIME,
@EndTime Datetime,
@args nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE #tbl (ID INT IDENTITY, IDEN INT, TIME1 DATETIME, V1 FLOAT NULL, V2 FLOAT NULL, V3 FLOAT NULL, V4 FLOAT NULL)
INSERT INTO #tbl EXEC SP_STATITISTICS_PACKAGE
SELECT * FROM #tbl
DROP TABLE #tbl
```

In the above example, I'm not passing any parameters to "SP_STATISTICS_PACKAGE", but that's just laziness on my part.
The main point is to demonstrate the syntax for populating a temp table via a nested stored procedure.  I'm explicitly dropping my temp table, however it should drop whenever the connection is closed.  If you run this USP more than once on the same connection without explicitly dropping it, you will receive a table exists error.
Also, I suggest using something more distinctive as a temp table name than #tbl.

Comment: So basically, you're suggesting to write a stored procedure where I call the external stored procedure which loads the data, inserts them in temporary table and then performs SELECT for all the statistical stuff needed, right?

Comment: That about sums it up.  You could also do all of the statistical stuff in the main stored procedure, if you wanted to.  Not being a front-end guy, I don't know which would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods to consider:

(1) Use the stored procedure returning a table, but always call it as:

```
insert into xxx
    exec(. . .)
```

Then you can use the table repeatedly, once for showing to the user and again for calculating statistics.

(2) Have a canonical table that will be populated when the stored procedure runs.  So the stored procedure in essence becomes:

```
truncate table xxx
do work
insert into xxx(...)
    <whatever should go here>
```

This works for single user systems where you don't have to worry about two users interfering with each other.

(3) Pass in a table name and populate it in the stored procedure.  But, you should only do this if your application is already making extensive use of dynamic SQL.  Under most circumstances, this is not highly recommended.

(4) (A variation on 2)  Maintain a history of all runs.  Include a runid in the table and pass back the runid.  The code then looks something like:

```
insert into runHistory(@RunId, . . .)
    select @RunId,  . . .
```

The stored procedure returns the @RunId, which is then used by the application.  With appropriate indexing, the size of the table should have little impact on performance.  Plus, you get to keep history.

(5) Probably the more recommended approach.  It looks like you are created a summary table on a daily basis.  Run the stored procedure each day to summarize the most recent data and just add it into a summary table.  This assumes that you do not need the most up-to-date information, so a day lag is acceptable.